# Rails 4.1, Ruby 2.1, Devise, Why 'syntax error, unexpected tConstant' in my .where() with multiple conditions?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I see from similar posts that it's usually a case of some closing character missing from a previous line, but I don't see it here. The Courses resource is nested inside Schools and I can print out both the user_id and the school.id.

The error appears to be in the Course.where clause with multiple conditions (user_id: current_user.id AND school_id: @school.id)
The one-condition where clause above it seems to work just fine.

courses_controller.rb

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_school

  helper_method :calculated_grade_stub


  # GET /courses
  # GET /courses.json
  def index
    if @school.nil?
      @courses = Course.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    else
      @courses = Course.where(user_id: current_user.id AND school_id: @school.id)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator is `&&` or `and`, not `AND`.

However, that's not the root cause of the problem: it appears you are confused about the general syntax of `Hash` literals. The entries in `Hash` literals are separated by comma, not by an operator:

```
@courses = Course.where(user_id: current_user.id, school_id: @school.id)
```

Note also that `if` is an expression and thus returns a value, so you can easily refactor that method to

```
def index
  @courses = if @school.nil?
    Course.where(user_id: current_user.id)
  else
    Course.where(user_id: current_user.id, school_id: @school.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried both. Didn't change the error.

Comment: It should change the error. It should now be `unexpected tLABEL`. Which should give you a hint at the underlying problem, namely that you don't really understand how `Hash` literals work, and then, when you think about how to write a `Hash` literal, you should realize that entries in `Hash` literals are separated by comma, not operators.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  @courses = Course.where('user_id = ? AND school_id = ?',current_user.id , @school.id)
```